# Practical ways to publish private jvm libraries to share between private gradle / maven projects in 2019

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, kotlin, artifactory

I'd like to refactor some of my recent code into a collection of kotlin multi-platform libraries. I then want to consume these libraries from multiple projects and ideally the build of these projects would be independent of my local dev machine.

Years ago I would just install Jenkins and hook it up to Artifactory but now I've bounced off this problem twice so far because Jenkins has just become incomprehensible. Artifactory has gotten quite heavy as well.

Is there a better way for small scale project like mine? I'm using github for source control, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to use Bazel for that:
https://bazel.build/

Bazel has good support for building artifacts from sources.

So in your case you could do something like:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
```

Then

```
your_commit = "f1882a3344a8b4d2669862a37ce45ce2ac1037ed"
http_archive(
    name = "just_a_name_you_would_use",
    urls = ["https://github.com/YourRepo/YourProject/archive/%s.zip" % rules_kotlin_version],
    type = "zip",
    strip_prefix = "YourProject-%s" % your_commit
)
```

Comment: I think this question is more about development infrastructure like build servers and artifact repositories. Bazel is just a build tool like Gradle or Maven, so I don't see how this answer is helpful.

Comment: @britter - disagree. Unlike Maven and Gradle, Bazel promotes building from sources. And servers and artifacts is exactly what author is trying to avoid here, by my understanding. But, as you're from Gradle, maybe you could provide an alternative answer :)

Comment: Gradle also supports source dependencies: https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies. I think answers to this question are primarily subjective, so I'm not going to add anything here :-)

Comment: That's relatively new, and I even wasn't aware of that. Thanks for sharing!